# Agrupar resultados de PHP a HTML de 2 en 2

Tags: php, html5

El problema que tengo es que quiero agrupar los resultados de una base de datos (los cuales ya obtuve en PHP y están almacenados en una variable tipo arreglo) y tengo un conjunto de elementos div donde por cada 2 registros quiero una fila distinta.

Los datos ya están en `$services`, y de ese objeto necesito mostrar en HTML lo siguiente: `$services[$i]['title']`, `$services[$i]['description']` y `$services[$i]['icon']`.

El HTML que lleva cada elemento distinto es este:

```html
<div class="single-offer d-flex flex-row pb-30">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="<?php echo $services->image; ?>" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $services->title; ?></h4></a>
    <p><?php echo $services->description; ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y para que cada dos registros se muestren en una fila nueva debe ir dentro de:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">

</div>
```

Lo que se me ocurre en PHP es un ciclo FOR con un IF dentro para evaluar con el operador MOD, pero no he logrado concertarlo. El total de registros en servicio lo tengo almacenado en `$totalServices;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Uso de FOR y MOD

El problema fue resuelto con un ciclo FOR. El código en PHP al final quedó así:

```
for($c=0; $c<$totalServices; $c++){
     if( ($c+1) % 2 == 1) echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
       ?>
       <div class="single-offer d-flex flex-row pb-30">
         <div class="icon">
           <img src="<?php echo $services[$c]['icon']; ?>" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="desc">
           <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $services[$c]['title']; ?></h4></a>
           <p><?php echo $services[$c]['description']; ?></p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <?php
     if( ($c) % 2 == 1) echo "</div><div style='clear:both;'></div>";
}
```

El operador % (Mod) sirve para obtener el residuo de una división, con lo que se pueden separar datos de dos en dos dentro de un ciclo FOR.

#### Evaluando pares e impares

Se usa `$c+1` en el primer IF para determinar si el numero es impar, dando como resultado un valor TRUE si el numero siguiente ($c+1) es par.

**En caso de serlo:** Se mostrara la primera etiqueta contenedora `<div class="col-lg-6">` .

**Caso contrario:** Simplemente se ignora la instrucción.

Para el final del FOR, se evalua si el valor actual es par. En caso de serlo, se cierra la etiqueta contenedora.

#### Adentrándose en el FOR

Una vez pasado al siguiente registro, ocurre exactamente lo mismo, evaluando cada vez cuando el siguiente numero sea par para abrir la etiqueta contenedora, y evaluando cuando el numero actual sea par para cerrarla.

La etiqueta anexada al final `<div style='clear:both;'></div>` es meramente control de diseño.

Con ésto mencionado, lo único que restaría es acomodar el HTML dentro del FOR para mostrar los datos.

**CSS Clear:** https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/css-avanzado/capitulo-1/limpiar-floats

**Operador Mod:** http://php.net/manual/es/internals2.opcodes.mod.php